# django fastest request between query and sub query

Tags: django, orm

If i have:

```
 class Record(models.Model):

     start_time = models.Integerfield()  Timestamp
```

And in a view I want to iterate over the days between start date and end date.

Is it faster to do :

```
 records = Record.objects.filter(
     start_time__gte=dt.datetime.timestamp(start_date),
     start_time__lt=dt.datetime.timestamp(end_date)
 )
 for start_day, stop_day in days_between_start_and_end_date:
      records_week = records.filter(
     start_time__gte=dt.datetime.timestamp(start_day),
     start_time__lt=dt.datetime.timestamp(stop_day)
 )
```

or directly

```
 for start_day, stop_day in days_between_start_and_end_date:
      records_week = Record.objects.filter(
     start_time__gte=dt.datetime.timestamp(start_day),
     start_time__lt=dt.datetime.timestamp(stop_day)
 )
```

In fact i tried and couldn't see any difference but I don't understand why because for me I am doing one big request in the first case and a lot of small one in the second cases. Any idea why ?

Comment: Remember that querysets are lazy. Neither of these examples execute any queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In both situations, you are not triggering the queryset to be evaluated. `filter` does nothing but composing sql statement in the underline implementation, so you never hit the database in either of the cases, you were just composing several sql statement that sits in your program. Only when you start using the variables then django starts to do the queryset evaluation.

Django doc about [querysets are lazy](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/queries/#querysets-are-lazy). If every orm statement is hitting the databsase it's not going to be optimal.